# Creating command lines with python (argparse)

Tags: pandas, argparse

I want to create a command line with python (argparse). The goal is to import a dataframe and then print its 5 first rows, however, when I run the command, this error shows up :

```
File "try.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\szouaoui\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.
```

it seems that the program is unable to import the pandas library

here is the code:

```
import argparse
import sys
import pandas as pd
my_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Unconstraining demand for specified dates, shops and categories/n')
my_parser.add_argument("path",type=str, action="store")
my_args = my_parser.parse_args()

input_file = sys.argv[1]
data = pd.read_csv(input_file)
print(data.head())
```

command line :

```
python try.py /path_to_file/dataframe_name.csv
```

Comment: Try to execute your command line using the `-m` flag, without the `.py` extension: 
`python -m try /path_to_file/dataframe_name.csv`

Comment: The same erros showed up, but it works when I run the command on the anaconda prompt, maybe because pandas is installed on anaconda

Comment: Sure. Try to run in a conda environment then, or install pandas and all it's dependencies