# Python argparse: command lines values are not initialised for optional values

Tags: python, argparse

I have the following arguments which are to be parsed using argparse

- input_dir (string: Mandatory)
- output_dir (string: Mandatory)
- file_path (string: Mandatory)
- supported_file_extensions (comma separated string - Optional)
- ignore_tests (boolean - Optional)

If either comma separated string and a string are provided for `supported_file_extensions` and `ignore_tests` respectively, then I want the value to be set to the argument variable. My set up is as follows

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        'input_dir', type=str,
        help='Fully qualified directory for the input directory')
    parser.add_argument(
        'file_path', type=str,
        help='Fully  qualified path name for file')
    parser.add_argument(
       'output', type=str, help='Fully qualified output directory path')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-supported_file_extensions',nargs='?', type=str, default=None,
        help='optional comma separated file extensions'
    ) # Should default to False
    parser.add_argument(
        '-ignore_tests', nargs='?', type=bool, default=True
    ) # Should default to True if the argument is passed
    (arguments, _) = parser.parse_known_args(sys.argv[1:])
    print(arguments)
```

When I pass the following command

```
 python cloc.py -input_dir /myproject -file_path /myproject/.github/CODEOWNERS -output output.json --supported_file_extensions java,kt --ignore_tests False
```

I want the value of the arguments.--supported_file_extensions to be equal to `java,kt` and `ignore_tests` to equal to `False` but I get the following values

```
Namespace(file_path='/myproject/.github/CODEOWNERS', ignore_tests=True, input_dir='/myproject', output='output.json', supported_file_extensions=None)
```

If I don't pass `--ignored_tests` in my command line argument, then I want the file to default to `False`. Similarly, when I pass `--ignored_tests`, then I want the argument to be set to `True`.

If I pass `--supported_file_extensions java,kt`, then I want the argument to be set to `java,kt` as a string, and not a list.

I have tried going through but I have not had any success.

1. [Python argparse: default value or specified value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301147/python-argparse-default-value-or-specified-value)
2. [python argparse default value for optional argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29847450/python-argparse-default-value-for-optional-argument)
3. [Creating command lines with python (argparse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61216374/creating-command-lines-with-python-argparse)

**UPDATE**
I updated the last two arguments as follows:

```
parser.add_argument(
        '-supported_file_extensions', type=str,
        help='optional comma separated file extensions'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '-ignore_tests', action='store_true',
        help='optional flag to ignore '
    )
    (arguments, _) = parser.parse_known_args(sys.argv[1:])
    print(arguments)
```

When I run the command as

```
  python cloc.py -input_dir /myproject -file_path /myproject/.github/CODEOWNERS -output output.json --supported_file_extensions java,kt
```

The output is as follows

```
 Namespace(file_path='/myproject/.github/CODEOWNERS', ignore_tests=False, input_dir='/myproject', output='output.json', supported_file_extensions=None)
```

While the value of `ignore_tests` is correct, (defaulted to false), the value of `supported_file_extensions` is `None`, which is not correct since I had passed `java,kt` as command line arguments.

When I pass

```
 python cloc.py -input_dir /myproject -file_path /myproject/.github/CODEOWNERS -output output.json --supported_file_extensions java,kt --ignore_tests
```

I get the following output

```
Namespace(file_path='/myproject/.github/CODEOWNERS', ignore_tests=False, input_dir='/myproject', output='output.json', supported_file_extensions=None)
```

Comment: Is there some reason the user must pass `True` or `False`? It's a *much* better idea to have them pass the switch, or not, with no value. The `action='store_true'` action will make that "just work", with no need to define `type`, `default`, or `nargs`. You definitely can't use the `bool` constructor, because `bool("True")` and `bool("False")` are both true (`bool` on a string is only false if the string is empty).

Comment: '--ignore-test' should be `action='store_true'`. (or 'store_false') Don't use `type=bool`.  And make up your mind, are the st 3 args postional of flagged, '--input_dir'

Comment: @ShadowRanger There is no requirement. I want a way to initialise either True or False to `ignore_tests` depending on the command line argument.

Comment: when I run code on Linux without arguments then it shows help message with `-supported_file_extensions` which has single `-` but you run it with double `--`. If I run it with double `--supported_file_extensions` then I get `None` but if I use single `-supported_file_extensions` then it gives correct value. You simply use `-` in wrong way. You should use single `-output` and double  `--supported_file_extensions`

Comment: If you define `add_argument('output')` then it expects value without `-output`. If you define with single `-` like `add_argument('-supported_file_extensions')` then you should run it also with single `-` like `-supported_file_extensions value`. If you want to use with double `--` like `--supported_file_extensions value` then you should define with double `--` like `add_argument('--supported_file_extensions')`

Comment: But I want to validate that `file_path`, `input_dir` and `output` are sent.

Answer (score 0):

Your arguments are incorrect. You are registering the arguments to the parser as `-ignore_tests` but specifying it on the command line as `--ignore_tests` — note the number of preceding dashes. You also do not need to specify `-input_dir` for the positional arguments, they do nothing.

Normally, both of the above issues would cause your script to crash. The only reason it still runs is because you are using `parser.parse_known_args` which ignores all arguments it doesn't understand — like `--ignore_tests` and `-input_dir`.

The command you should be running is:

```sh
python cloc.py /myproject /myproject/.github/CODEOWNERS output.json -supported_file_extensions java,kt -ignore_tests False
```

Also, as many in the comments have mentioned, do not use `type=bool` when registering arguments. Instead, use

```py
parser.add_argument('-ignore_tests', action='store_true')
```

This will set `ignore_tests` to `True` when `-ignore_tests` is present and `False` otherwise — no need to explicitly specify `True` or `False` on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a better definition:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '--input_dir',
        help='Fully qualified directory for the input directory')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--file_path',
        help='Fully  qualified path name for file')
    parser.add_argument(
       '--output', help='Fully qualified output directory path')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--supported_file_extensions',
        help='optional comma separated file extensions'
    ) # only use ? if defining default and const
    parser.add_argument(
        '--ignore_tests', action='store_true'
    )
    (arguments, extras) = parser.parse_known_args()
    print(arguments)
    print(extras)
```

Call with:

```
python cloc.py --input_dir /myproject --file_path /myproject/.github/CODEOWNERS --output output.json --supported_file_extensions java,kt
```

Another version:

if **name** == '**main**':
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

```
parser.add_argument(
    '--supported_file_extensions',
    help='optional comma separated file extensions')
parser.add_argument(
    '--ignore_tests', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument(
    'input_dir',
    help='Fully qualified directory for the input directory')
parser.add_argument(
    'file_path',
    help='Fully  qualified path name for file')
parser.add_argument(
    'output', help='Fully qualified output directory path')
(arguments, extras) = parser.parse_known_args()
print(arguments)
print(extras)
```

Call with:

```
python cloc.py --ignore_tests /myproject /myproject/.github/CODEOWNERS output.json --supported_file_extensions java,kt
```

The `optionals` (--) can be in any order, but `positionals` have to be in the given order.  No flags or keywords for the `positionals`.

Comment: I want to be able to pass the command line keys though.

Comment: What do you mean by `command line keys`?  Test my code and look at the `Namespace`.  If you want different behavior, you might want to parse `sys.argv` directly.

Comment: I may be wrong but if one passes `--{key} value`, then it means that the values are optional, aren't they? I want the first three to be mandatory.

Comment: You could set `required=True`.  Or just give them reasonable defaults, so you don't care.  Or make them `positionals` (but then you can't use flag words in the input).

Comment: Your suggestion worked for me. If you can update your answer with `required=True`, then I can accept it.